# how to integrate firebase performance monitoring in Android

Tags: android, performance, firebase

Hi I need to monitor my methods and network calls performance in Android using Android Studio. Anyone help me out?

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler

Comment: I need to monitor using firebase

Comment: So is this https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android

Comment: Can you give me steps in more details.

Comment: Sorry I don't have try this so I can't.

Comment: 1. You should have found this link yourself, had you bothered searching by yourself, but you were lazy. 2. You got the link out of luck, but instead of going through it and trying for yourself, you requested more help immediately, which is a clear indication of help vampire issues. 3. You never say thank you, also a good indicator. Please consider abandoning your parasite ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to project level `build.gradle` and add

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        //Your gradle version example classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        //play services plugin example classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

App level `build.gradle` add `apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'` below `com.android.application`

In dependencies add `firebase-perf`

```
android.applicationVariants.all {
    // Set this to false to disable Firebase Performance Monitoring at compile time
    FirebasePerformance {
        instrumentationEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies{
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
}
```

At the bottom add below line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

You can monitor Network request, traces and method response time by adding below code in activity or class

```
@AddTrace(name = "devcie_info", enabled = true)
getdeviceInfo(){}
```

For Traces

```
Trace myTrace = FirebasePerformance.getInstance().newTrace("test_trace");
myTrace.start();
getdeviceInfo(){}
myTrace.stop();
```

Network Requests

```
HttpMetric metric = FirebasePerformance.getInstance().newHttpMetric(url, FirebasePerformance.HttpMethod.GET);
```

On response set response code and payload size

```
metric.setRequestPayloadSize(response.length());
metric.setHttpResponseCode(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
metric.stop();
```

For detailed information go to [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android)

Comment: Yes it is really helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: read this also https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android